# Postgres greedy regex behaves as reluctant

Tags: regex, postgresql

I composed almost whole question and then found answer so I will put it here in Q&A style anyway because the described behaviour seems surprising to me.

This regex works correctly and splits string to three parts - numerical part surrounded with letter parts:

```
select regexp_replace('abc12345def', '^(.*?)([0-9]+)(.*)$', '{first="\1" second="\2" third="\3"}');

{first="abc" second="12345" third="def"}
```

However after removal of `^` and `$` anchors I get

```
select regexp_replace('abc12345def', '(.*?)([0-9]+)(.*)', '{first="\1" second="\2" third="\3"}');

{first="abc" second="1" third=""}2345def
```

Because the groups 2 and 3 have greedy quantifier I expect them to match `12345` and `def`, respectively, and hence return the same string. Equivalent Java code behaves this way:

```
System.out.println("abc12345def".replaceFirst("(.*?)([0-9]+)(.*)", "{first='$1' second='$2' third='$3'}"));
System.out.println("abc12345def".replaceFirst("^(.*?)([0-9]+)(.*)$", "{first='$1' second='$2' third='$3'}"));

{first='abc' second='12345' third='def'}
{first='abc' second='12345' third='def'}
```

Why does not it work?

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/zvAbyyNQ)

Answer (score 0):

Greediness in regular expressions in Postgres is set as a whole. Essentially same example as the provided one can be found in [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html#POSIX-MATCHING-RULES) with explanation:

> `SELECT regexp_match('abc01234xyz', '(.*?)(\d+)(.*)');`
>
> `Result: {abc,0,""}`
>
> That didn't work either, because now the RE as a whole is non-greedy and so it ends the overall match as soon as possible. We can get what we want by forcing the RE as a whole to be greedy:...

Solution is to force whole regex to be greedy:

```
select regexp_replace('abc12345def', '(?:(.*?)([0-9]+)(.*)){1,1}', '{first="\1" second="\2" third="\3"}');

{first="abc" second="12345" third="def"}
```

Slightly counterintuitive for me but works.

Comment: Isn't `'(.*)(\d+)(.*)'` simpler? Greediness is set NOT "as a whole", it is set with the FIRST QUANTIFIER.